# SIPDemo doesn't send or receive a call

Tags: android, sip, demo

I am trying to make SIPDemo sample work to test SIP API for 2.3.1. It installed on my 2.3.3 device without any problem but when I call from the phone or to the phone after saving SIP credentials, it does not do anything. Did anybody have a success with the demo app? If so, could you tell me what I am supposed to do to make it work? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using SipDemo if you want to call any SIP number then you have to append VOIP server IP Address with SIP number. For example if you want to make call on 221 then you have to dial 221@192.168.15.11

where 192.168.15.11 is VOIP server IP address and 221 is SIP number..

Comment: You are right. I am testing an sip implementation with sipjs on the browser, but I can't hear in the browser where I received the call. Do you have an idea why that happens?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not a lot of information you give here. Do you have your own SIP proxy set up or are you using a public one?
Maybe make some network captures with something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and post the results here. Telling you what's not working is not possible otherwise.

also, have you tried to connect with the built-in SIP client in android 2.3? Is that one working?

Comment: I have SIP accounts from SIP providers (one for termination service and one for receiving SIP calls). I used their credentials in that app. I think I've tried everything including wireshark at the time as I have proxy server. I couldn't get any signal from the app. What do you mean by built-in SIP client? What is the name of it? I have an app for sip calling. It's working fine.

Comment: From android 2.3 onwards there is a built-in (or native) SIP client installed. The thing is, that it is not actually an app (like e.g. SipDroid) but rather built into the system itself. You should be able to set it up with the help of this [android 2.3 user guide](http://www.scribd.com/doc/44779923/Android-2-3-User-s-Guide#outer_page_75) on page 75. I hope this helps you somehow.

Comment: Oh, you mean SIP client that is integrated with phone app. I actually know there is source code for it but wondered how I can access on the device. I will try it for sure. Once I succeeded, I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: I cannot find internet calling option in my call setting. Any idea how to enable it?

Comment: are you sure you're phone has android 2.3 on it? Because if you don't, it also would make a lot of sense that you cannot see any data transferred on the network. how could it if the relevant android core libraries are missing.
Checking your android version: Settings->about phone->Android version. This should be at least 2.3.1

Comment: Mine is 2.3.3. I know because I upgraded myself.

Comment: well, unless you didn't install some special version, it should be there. what phone do you have? Try following the instructions on [this link](http://www.voipvoip.com/android/sip.html). Did it work now?

Comment: I have [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241756/failed-to-create-sipsession-network-unavailable), did you manage to resolve this?